# How to resolve error with kivymd togglebutton

Tags: python, kivymd

I am trying to use ToggleButtons in KivyMD but i am getting an error:

self.background_normal = self.md_bg_color[:]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I checked out the kicyMd docs  and the example given here https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/behaviors/togglebutton/
is giving the same error....

Any ideas on this would be great

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.behaviors.toggle_behavior import MDToggleButton 
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton

KV = ''' Screen:

    MDBoxLayout:
        adaptive_size: True
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

        MyToggleButton:
            text: "Show ads"
            group: "x"

        MyToggleButton:
            text: "Do not show ads"
            group: "x"

        MyToggleButton:
            text: "Does not matter"
            group: "x" '''


class MyToggleButton(MDRectangleFlatButton, MDToggleButton):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.background_down = self.theme_cls.primary_light


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Test().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this problem has already been fixed in the master version of the KivyMD library.Try updating the library.